# Photoshop: How to change / remove background color with shadow?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have an image:
[image]

As you can see there are white parts to the cherry (the tip, and the white stuff on the side and in the middle.

I'd like to change everything other than those parts that is white to another color. How would I do this?

Whenever I do it with the background eraser tool, it makes my image look crappy. But when I do something like changing the Hue slider while making certain RGB channels invisible, it seems to give me the desired effect (although it gives me no control over what color I want exactly).

This is how I am partially able to achieve the color change that I want now. The only thing is I can't choose a specific color.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no automatic way to achieve this because the software can't distinguish one white part of the image from another. The quickest way to get the effect that you are looking for is as follows:

1. Create a background layer with the colour that you want (yellow in this example)
2. Place your source image on top of this and set the opacity mode to MULTIPLY
3. Draw a shape for the areas that you want to be white (or whatever colour) and place it in between the background and the image

Like this:
[image]

The shape that goes in between to mask out the background could be a SHAPE layer or you could just draw a PATH and FILL it with a colour. Either will work. If you're not sure how to do that then do a search for PHOTOSHOP plus the other words that I have put in CAPS and you'll find plenty of tutorials.